# Remove characters from url hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wanting to remove characters from a hash in a url

side bar create url with anchor

e.g

html/g_later_life_lett.html#3.-what-is-important?everything!

```
var test = window.location.hash;
$(test).replace('?', '')
```

so when page loads it looks af any ? and ! in hash and removes them.

thanks for help

---

Updated: thanks add this works fine now

```
var currentHash = window.location.hash;
var cleanHash = currentHash.replace(/[?!]/g, "");
window.location.hash = cleanHash;
```

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery. you can do this with JavaScript string replace method. Have a look at my answer below to figure out how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery. you can do this with [JavaScript string replace method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

```js
var test = "html/g_later_life_lett.html#3.-what-is-important**?-everything!**";
test = test.replace(/[?!]/g, "")
console.log(test);
```

The regular expression `/[?!]/g` selects all `?` and `!` from the input string.

**g**: stands for global. And then I am replacing all occurrences with empty string.

Comment: op asked to remove both `?` and `!`, wich can be done in one call. this might be confusing and lead to op using 2 replace's for one string

Comment: yes. modified my answer. op just edited the question. Earlier op had mentioned only `?`

Answer (score 0):

this will remove all the ? and ! in a string:

```js
let str = "html/g_later_life_lett.html#3.-what-is-important?everything!"

console.log(str.replace(/[?!]/g,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
var test = window.location.hash;
var newTest = $(test).replace(/(\?|!)/gm, '');
```

Put the two `/` marks in to use a regular expression instead of simply a simple string search.
You can also test your regex here: https://regex101.com/.